# WinForms background color on Windows 7

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c#-4.0

I have a .Net application cotaining a form which is displayed as dialog box. This works great on windows XP but when I run this EXE on Windows 7 the form background color changes to black.

Comment: What is the BackColor property of your Windows form?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ActiveCaptionText will indeed show up as black in Windows 7, this is standard behaviour. On Windows XP, ActiveCaptionText shows up as white as shown below:

[image: ActiveCaptionText]

I think you need to change the BackColor property to `Control` to get your form to look like how you want it:

[image: Control]

Comment: Technically, it will go to whatever the current theme setting is within Windows. If you want to always be sure of the color make sure to specify it absolutely.

Comment: True, my answer assumes the default colours haven't been changed

Comment: Notice that in the first screenshot, the colors match those of the title bar text, which is what is meant by ActiveCaptionText...